# How can I include new lines for code snippets inside comments?

Tags: support, comments, code-formatting

I want to write short code in a comment like:

```
function ngWrap($scope, fn) {
    return function() {
        var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
        if (!$scope.$$phase) {
            fn.apply(null, args);
        } else {
            return $scope.$apply(function() {
                fn.apply(null, args);
            });
        }
    };
}
```

But when I put the code in backticks, the newlines are removed when rendered. How can I insert code into a comment, like on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23674590/angularjs-value-wont-change-with-settimeout/23674681#answer-23674681)?

Comment: Don't. Comments are not supposed to be used for extensive code examples. Use answers instead. Or link to a gist.

Comment: I disagree. There should be a place for discussions, quotes and code examples that are related to the question without actually _answering_ anything. The comment boxes are awfully limited. Particularly, the best kind of questions create a need for this. You could have several experts of a topic debating, quoting standards etc and trying to find a consensus or demonstrating why they believe that a posted answer is incorrect. The limited comment boxes also limit the amount of intellectual activity on the site. But I better stop writing this comment now, because I'm running out of characters.

Comment: @Oded: But any answer must still be an answer, right? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300458/is-tangential-information-not-an-answer

Comment: @Oded, when I tried following your advice, I was chastised mercilessly for using an answer where I should have used a comment. This problem isn't an Issue with languages like `Perl/C,` but is a _big_ issue with languages that rely on formatting, like `Python,` to say nothing when you want to include a few lines of a *stack-dump*...

Comment: @Oded - You could still have short comments with short code examples that would be more readable if a newline were allowed for. E.g., [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54776489/find-which-file-was-used-by-an-include-directive?noredirect=1#comment96418774_54776489).
You mean to demonstrate a point with a description ("extensive code") that is not the general case (even if I guess it applies to the example in the OP).

Comment: Great readability question: !`newline`Look at the `[return]` key on your keyboard. You will notice that it is larger than punctuation characters keys, and than any alphabetic character key. Do you guess why?

Comment: @dan sorry I don't understand what is your question.

Comment: @dan Because modern keyboards are modeled after typewriters, where the carriage return button had to physically move the carriage back to the left of the paper, and shift the paper up one line. It required more physical effort to do that than for a normal key, so they made the key larger to accommodate using multiple fingers to press it. Now, what does that have to do with being able to add new lines to comments?

Comment: The `[return]` key on any keyboard is much important than anyone except `[space]` on your keyboard because this key is fundamental as space to bring a minimal level of readeability of any form of text.
`[return]` is not any form of advanced formatting. It is an elementary function to maintain readability of any text.

Comment: @dan I don't understand what it has to do with my question.

Comment: I haven't checked, but I believe this works on Codidact. There are still restrictions on what Markdown and/or HTML is supported in comments, but code blocks and blockquotes are supposed to work IIRC.

Comment: So you want to react to answer, using that many text with important formatting so that a comment is not suited? Then why don't you simply edit the answer, adding a title like **Edited after this particular insight** and you put your source there. Additionally, you can add a comment, explaining to the answer author what you have done and why and he or she can decide whether or not to leave your edit.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Comments are meant to be ... comments. That is why there are a cap on maximum length and a minimal support for text formatting.

Pasting that code snippet in your answer seems to be okay.

Comment: I first, put it in comment because it was not related to the question but to the comment, but it was not looking good so I just put the function in answer and the use if it as comment.

Comment: What should I do if I need to paste multiple line of code in comment box as a question in any discussion.

Comment: @PlanetHackers: Reconsider if you _really_ need those linebreaks. That said, that much code isn't suitable for the comments section.

Comment: @Cerbrus, languages like `Python` _insist_ on a certain format for the lines, which the comments clobber.

Comment: Blocks of pythong code really aren't suitable for comments though

Comment: What about short paragraphs? It really helps to be able to format your text into readable chunks, even if you only get 600 or so characters. Also, why is code unsuitable for comments? What if you're *discussing* code and it would be even more unsuitable to post a new answer? Using pastebin or the like is clearly suboptimal...

Comment: _That is why they have a cap on maximum length and a minimal support for text formatting_ . As there is a cap on the total length of the comment, how does it follow that code formatting should not be supported. The example in the question is about 300 characters long, well bellow the 600 character cap.

Answer (score 4):

You can't and there is no good reason you should as far as I can tell. The (unofficial) replies seem to focus on the size of an individual comment. This is already addressed by the overall cap on the comment size which is 600 characters at the moment.

In my opinion, it is up to the commenter to deal with the cap in whichever way she sees fit and if she wants to use some of the character budget on a code block it should be up to her. Your example is about 300 characters long and fits comfortably within the cap.

In many (most? all?) programming languages, code tends to be less ambiguous and carry more information per character than straight prose.

I was about to comment on an answer that contains a code example. It is a good answer and a good example but times move on and the syntax has evolved so that slight modification of the code provides a cleaner solution. Gave up on that due to the lack of code formatting in comments.

Comment: What do you think of this comment style: `[newline]`
making the need for a newline fully explicit?

Answer (score -7):

Newlines are not preserved in comments because Stack Exchange says so.

If you want to add to an existing answer, e.g. with some lines of code or a list of steps to follow, your only options are to edit it into the existing answer or post a new answer and refer to it in a comment.

Even though editing the question or answer or posting a new answer is often less helpful and appropriate than just commenting on an existing answer, these are the only work-arounds if you need multiple lines.

Comment: You have quite some reputation, but you use this as Forum. StackOverflow is not a forum it's a Q&A website even Meta.

Comment: [*Stack Overflow* is not a forum](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92115).

Answer (score -18):

If, for Question / Answers
Select code in edit mode and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>. If required, for keys enclose in an XML kbd starting and /kbd ending tag and enclose in an XML snippet starting and /snippet ending tag for code:

```
System.out.println("Hello, World!")
```

**But for comments the same cannot be done.**

Comment: This misunderstands the question completely. It is about code in **comments**, not questions or answers.

Comment: I agree @Karl, it went misleading cause the question was about comments not just post. probably, it might help someone just posting Question / Answers, so I have edited the same as suggested by you. Thanks for helping me fix the same Karl.. :)