# Is tangential information not an answer?

Tags: discussion, not-an-answer, specific-answer

I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5781268/c-sharp-operator/8741308#8741308) via a [Low Quality Posts review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/8976574).  In a nutshell, the question can be summed up by its final line:

> What is the `=>` operator actually doing? Is it overriding something?

The "answer" is

> I personally don't like them. But it's a matter of taste. It makes code hard to read for someone who is reviewing another person's code. I much prefer abstracting it into a proper, old-school, named function so that the code is 1) easier to read and 2) easier to re-use and refactor.

IMO, this is not a valid attempt to answer the question.  It *maybe tangentially* answers the questions by implying a similarity with "named functions", but it feels more like an opinion piece that never addresses the core question.

My questions:

- Does this answer it fit the Not-An-Answer flag criteria?
- If I were to flag this as NAA would it be marked helpful?
- Would reviewing it as <kbd>Recommend Deletion</kbd> be appropriate? If so, what comment should I leave?

Comment: Not an Answer, it does not attempt to answer the question. It is just an opinion statement.

Comment: If you select "Recommend Deletion", make sure you downvote it to a net score of 0 or less, otherwise it won't actually get deleted, it'll just end up in another queue for moderators to review, wherein they can delete it, but hey, why give them more work? :)

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables would it also help to throw a NAA flag on too if I go that route?  Or is it redundant?

Comment: @ryanyuyu - I believe it's redundant, since it's already in the queue.  Now, if it *doesn't* get deleted for some reason (3 Looks Good, or has a net score of 1+ when the sixth deletion vote is cast), you can throw a NAA flag and start the process all over again.  I think.

Comment: The NAA flag states "It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether."  An answer like that is just a comment in disguise, so fits under NAA in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for the advice so far.  I ended up recommending deletion and taking @LittleBobbyTables advice of also dropping a downvote and flagging as NAA.  There was also another similar opinion-answer that I flagged as NAA.

Comment: That's a fine comment. Not an answer tho

Comment: It doesn't answer the question, so is not an answer. I might call it an answer if "It does this, but that's bad, so why not do that instead".

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Tangential information is **not** an answer.  Let's look at the [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page:

> Read the question carefully. What, specifically, is the question asking for? Make sure your answer provides that – or a viable alternative. The answer can be “don’t do that”, but it should also include “try this instead”. Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful, but do try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer.

That tangential information is not providing an answer or an alternative.

Comment: I visit the help center often to research this kind of stuff, but I completely overlooked this page.  Just a devil's advocate question: Does "_I much prefer abstracting it into a proper, old-school, named function_" count as a viable alternative?

Comment: @ryanyuyu It is not an attempt to answer the question of, "what is this thing?".  Now if the question had asked how to solve something, and it used lambdas to do it, then you could post an answer that used a named function instead *to still solve the problem*.  Here the problem *is* understand what a lambda is, and using a named function doesn't even attempt to answer that.

Comment: @Servy ah thanks.  That was the final aspect I was having trouble judging.  Now it's super clear to me that NAA is the most appropriate choice.

Answer (score 0):

This post should *not* have been flagged as Not an Answer. It should have been flagged with Other.

We've received an awful lot of guidance telling us that, "No, the content of the question doesn't matter. NAA flags are only appropriate when it's not even close to looking like it could possibly be an answer when viewed out of context." See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286476/1394393) for the most recent guideline, which is to use an Other flag. Extensive discussion can be found at [A minor change to the description of the 'not an answer' flag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/286229/1394393). If a moderator happened to handle this flag, it would be declined under these guidelines.

For this specific answer, the question could conceivably be something along the lines of, "Are there any downsides to using lambdas in C#?" This of course has nothing to do with the actual question, but it could conceivably be an answer to *some* question that has something to do with this site's subject matter. It's not a good answer even then, but under current policy, this would seem to disqualify it for an NAA flag.

(Disclaimer: This post should not be construed as supporting the current policy. It merely states it.)

That said, if it's already in the queue, deleting it is fine. Use the **This is commentary on another post, not an answer** reason when voting to delete.

Comment: But that is exactly true, it's not even close to looking like an answer.

Comment: @LeoNatan I thought the same thing, but apparently the NaA flag should only be used for posts which do not appear to attempt to answer any question. So even if it does not answer the question at hand, it is *an* answer. Questions or gratitude posted as an answer are not answers.

Comment: @LeoNatan Please read the resources I linked to. These are instructions from moderators and StackExchange staff. I agree it's not logical given the wording of the flag's description, but this is what we're asked to do.