# How should I handle this post in LQ review?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, low-quality-posts

The answerer states that this is a comment, but to me, it looks like an answer as it includes a lot of explanation. This is the link to the [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/31988145).

There are many downsides to this post, such as the usage of links without including the important details, and not including a direct answer (by which I mean it may contain some unnecessary stuff too). Also, it looks pretty long for a comment (which the answerer asks any administrator to convert it to).

How should I be handling this post which looks like an answer (but may or may not be it exactly)?

**EDIT**: The general consensus was **Looks OK** for that post. I see many agreeing to the [possibly related link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300458/is-tangential-information-not-an-answer) provided by @Andrew T in the comments. It would be really nice if any mod can provide an answer to what really should be done to that post.

Comment: Whilst I'm sure it's useful, it's not really an answer. Answers should actually *answer* the question at hand, rather than speculate and half-answer it. I would recommend to delete in this case. You're right to ask here for advice, but it's always best to just **skip** the review if you don't know what to do.

Comment: The users request for *"if an admin could convert this into a comment."* would be impossible too; the content is *far* too long for a comment.

Comment: When an answer starts off by saying, “I don’t have enough reputation to comment”, it typically means the answer is actually a comment. In this case the author of the answer, specifically says their answer, is actually a comment.  If you can edit out the part(s) that make it a comment, you might be able to save the answer from being deleted, but there are far better contributions that should be improved that are actually answers so it might not be worth the effort

Comment: @Larnu Yes, that's why I have included that in my question.

Comment: @user438383 I haven't made any decision yet. I was thinking to skip it but decided to ask a question first!

Comment: Possibly related: [Is tangential information not an answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/300458/2821954).

Comment: `the answer is ok as it is, and so should be reviewed as Looks OK.

Comment: @nbk Is this your answer to the question and if so, why did you post it as an comment? ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First if you are **unsure** about an answer or question in a review, **skip it**.

To your question, it looks ok.

the user tries to answer the question, with a lot of unnecessary text, which warrants a good cleaning up.

But that was not the review question, you should judge about, did the user try to answer the question and of course he did try.

You can argue, if it is a good answer, but for that is the voting function a better place.

you must only take a good look at the answer in this case and judge if the answers

> are on-topic, sufficiently detailed, and not too broad. Use this option for answers that answer the question as asked, even if they may be incorrect.

And not

> - questions or answers that are very short, in the wrong language or gibberish
> - new or follow-up questions written as answers
> - answers that do not attempt to answer the question asked, or that contain only links and no explanation
> - comments entered as answers (e.g. “I have the same question” or “thanks for the great answer”)

All above is copied from the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality)