# Is there an online editor to automate Comment formatting and editing?

Tags: support

It's very tricky to comment on a question (to clarify the replier's suspicions), especially if the reply has punctuation marks, code, line breaks, etc.

So I wanted to know is there any easy way to it? Is there any online editor which can auto-format it? I am new and I am finding it very difficult to format comments. Your defined formatting rules aren't straightforward and 100% working which makes my/other users' jobs difficult.

Comment: Did you click on `help` next to the comment box? It gives you handy advice inline and links to http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

Comment: Yes I tried that the tricky one especially if I am replying as comment. I have added 4 spaces at start and also 2 at the end of line but still it shows few lined without break. For this sake only I am asking Is there any online editor  which can help.

Comment: You can't show multiline code blocks in a comment, that's why it's not covered in the help.

Comment: Why to vote -ve ? Is not a valid question ? Like "geeksforgeeks"  has editor to auto format code and then just cut paste job left to post it . So I was wondering is there any similar way to do it here, what is wrong with question ?

Comment: [What is "meta"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) may answer your question about voting on Meta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, There is no such online editor available.

Answer (score 3):

This is all you need to know to comment :

```
*italics*
**bold**
***bold and italics***
`code`
[link text](url)
```

I don't understand why would you ask a question like this when all this comes up to you on the right side in a pop up?

*Click the `help link` under [add comment] to see a summary of the available formatting options.*

Comment: What if I want to paste few line from some file in comment, How to make sure there will be the break at EOL for sure .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include new lines for code snippets inside comments?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254976/how-to-include-new-lines-for-code-snippets-inside-comments)

Comment: @ypp You haven't opened the duplicate link have you?
Comments are not meant for code.

Comment: Even I don't want to write code in reply but i want to write the output of the code one after another in reply.